# Advanced jQuery Tutorials

Tags: jquery, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning jQuery and Getting Better at Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787271/learning-jquery-and-getting-better-at-javascript)

I have found jQuery very interesting JS tool, using which we can achieve some great functionalities not only in websites but into iPhone side as well.

do you guys, have some good references, where i can find some good help/guide and see some more innovative things / idea to learn from.

Also some references like manual or so, would be much appreciated.

Comment: [jQuery Manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may find countless references and tutorials all over the web, I would like to take this space to recommend Bibeault and Katz's excellent book, "[jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/)". This was the book I thoroughly absorbed, page to page, word to word, when I sat down to start with `jQuery`. The book starts with the basics, and goes on to touch some of the more advanced, but highly interesting features of `jQuery`, using practical and fun-to-go-through examples. It's a wonderful read.